# Regex is not working for mix symbol and hyphen

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex validation rule like below:

1. Contain alpha numeric only
2. Can have `-`, `_` and `/`
3. Can have one space in the beginning and many at the end
4. Can mix symbols

For example:

```
aaa-bbb/ccc
aaa
1223/aaa-bbb 
aaa-bbb-ccc
```

I try with the following code and its not working for mix symbol and for `-`. Any idea how to handle it?

```
@"^((?:/[a-za-z0-9]+)+/?|/?(?:[a-za-z0-9]+/)+)[a-za-z0-9]*$"
```

Comment: Don't rules 2 and 3 contradict rule 1?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this regex work for you:

```
/^ ?[a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]+ *$/gm
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oQ5eH7). That is made to do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: thanks I try it and somehow its not working for something like this: dfasfsd,any idea?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/cV7nM2 It seems to work just fine for that. Are you sure it's not a problem somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%5E%28%28%3F%3A/%5Ba-za-z0-9%5D+%29+/%3F%7C/%3F%28%3F%3A%5Ba-za-z0-9%5D+/%29+%29%5Ba-za-z0-9%5D%2a%24&env=env_java) is an analysis of your regex. As you can see it is far too complicated and nowhere near what you're looking for.

Assuming I'm interpreting your conditions correctly, your basic regex should probably look something like:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+$"
```

That's it. It contains alpha-numeric only, also allowing `-`, `_` and `/`, allowing mixed symbols. I'm afraid I don't know what you mean in condition 3, but maybe adding `\s?` just after the `^` and `\s*` just before the `$` should do it.

Comment: Thanks I've try it and the problem is that when I enter one space at the beginning i got error and also I need also to provide the option to add spaces-es  at the end of the value and this also cause error,any idea?

Comment: Did you try adding the `\s?` and `\s*` I described?